# Do I have to pay for a development card if I have a joker and the card needs only one type of resource?

Tags: splendor

Yesterday I've been introduced to *Splendor* (awesome game!), and there's one question stuck in my head. In one turn I've run out of options (no resources to collect, nothing to buy), so I reserved a card with a joker token. After some turns I bought it, and payed the full price (4 blue gems), and gave the joker token back.

Only afterwards did I realise that I didn't have to pay since I had the joker token - but does it work like this for a development card that requires *only one* colour?

Can I reserve a card that only requires one colour, nd then take it in the next turn by only giving the joker token?

Comment: A Gold Joker token can be used in place of a single other resource token during a purchase (*any* purchase). It's never "returned". It's not used to reserve a card (it is *provided* to you as part of the same action).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the rules:

> **Buying a development card**
>
> ...
>
> A joker token can replace any color.

This means that a Gold Joker token can be used in place of any **single** other token as part of **any** purchase.

In particular,

1. The Joker can be used to purchase a card from the center, not just the one you reserved.
2. The Joker does not replace **all** tokens of a given color, just one.

This second point is perhaps not quite clear from that rules quote, but the other interpretation would make them far too powerful. You can confirm that this is how jokers work by experimenting with them in the official app version of the game.

Comment: Official app? Didn't know about that. Perhaps this is a translation issue. I wonder what the French (I assume it's the original language) version of the rules says about this. Thank you nonetheless ;)